# Data_wrap_struct and mark function

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

Im writing a Ruby extension and Im using the function `Data_wrap_struct`.

In order to participate in Ruby's mark-and-sweep garbage collection process, I need to define a routine to free my structure, and a routine to mark any references from my structure to other structures. I pass the classic `free` function to free the memory but I dont know how to use a mark function.

my structs sound like this

```
typedef struct
{
  int x;
  int y;
} A;

typedef struct
{
  A collection[10];
  int current;
} B;
```

I think that I need a mark function to mark the references in `collection` of struct B.

Someone can show me a example to see how a mark function works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mark function is used to mark any *Ruby objects* that your C structure owns.

```
typedef struct {
    VALUE ruby_object;
} MyStruct;

void mark(void * p) {
    /* p is the wrapped pointer to the MyStruct instance */
    MyStruct * my_struct = (MyStruct *) p;
    rb_gc_mark(my_struct->ruby_object);
}
```

If the object owned by your structure isn't marked, the garbage collector could sweep it and your code may end up trying to use a finalized object.

Comment: Do I need to mark also non-Ruby objects which are referenced by other Ruby objects? In my case I have a tree of widgets created by other Ruby classes (with references to them).

Comment: @Izap, no. The `mark` function is used to tell Ruby's garbage collector about **Ruby objects** which were created from code external to the Ruby virtual machine, such as a C extension. If you have on your hands a Ruby object which creates other native non-Ruby objects, you might want to implement a `free` function which releases resources once the Ruby object is garbage-collected.